# Are avatars (like gravatars) findable from a phone number?

Tags: avatar, gravatar

I know that I can use gravatar.org's simple API to find somebody's "Gravatar" if they have signed up using an email address.

Is there a similar service which attaches "avatars" (or profile pictures) to phone numbers?

I used gravatar.org API on an email address, and retrieved the person's "gravatar".
I would like to know if there is anything similar which would work on a phone number without an email address.